# Polynomial finding given as limit results

Tags: calculus, limits, polynomials

Given that p(x) is a fourth-degree polynomial with the coefficient of the highest degree term equal to 1, find p(3). p(1) and p(2) are known as following.

$$ \lim_{{x \to 1}} \frac{p(x)}{x - 1} = p(1) $$
$$ \lim_{{x \to 2}} \frac{p(x)}{x - 2} = p(2) $$

The solution is the following

> Since we have given that p is a polynomial that means p(1) and p(2)
> defined and finite then from 1 and 2 we have a factor  in polynomial ,
> since limit must exist so we have let
>
> $\mathrm{{p}{\left({x}\right)}} =
>  \mathrm{{\left({x}-{1}\right)}{\left({x}-{2}\right)}{q}{\left({x}\right)}}
>  \:\:\:\:\:\text{(1)}\\[3pt]\mathrm{{p}{\left({1}\right)}} =
>  \mathrm{{0}{\quad\text{and}\quad}{p}{\left({2}\right)}={0}}
>  \:\:\:\:\text{(2)}$
>
> Then from above and given condition we get
>
> $\mathrm{{p}{\left({x}\right)}} =
>  \mathrm{{\left({x}-{1}\right)}^{{2}}{\left({x}-{2}\right)}^{{2}}} $
>
> Therefore this polynomial satisfy all condition of above. Then we get
> that
>
> $\mathrm{{p}{\left({3}\right)}} =
>  \mathrm{{\left({3}-{1}\right)}^{{2}}{\left({3}-{2}\right)}^{{2}}={4}}$

I don't understand from where $q(x)$ comes from and how $\mathrm{{p}{\left({x}\right)}} =
 \mathrm{{\left({x}-{1}\right)}^{{2}}{\left({x}-{2}\right)}^{{2}}} $ is found. Could you please explain? It is really hard to follow.

Comment: $q$ comes from dividing $p$ by $x-1$ and $x-2$. The question is, how do we know that $p$ is divisible by those. Note that if the first limit exists, and since the denominator $x-1$ tends to $0$, then the numerator must also tend to $0$. But the limit of the numerator is $p(1)$. So, $p(1)=0$. This tells that $x=1$ is a root of $p$, and therefore $p$ is divisible by $x-1$. Same for the second limit.

Comment: Then the final form comes from finding out that $q$ is again divisible by $x-1$ and $x-2$. To see this, put $p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)q(x)$ in the two limits and use that $p(1)=p(2)=0$. From the first limit you get that $q(1)=p(1)=0$. So, $q$ is divisible by $x-1$.

Comment: @NDB hard to understand but thank you. I solved it in my way.

Answer (score 1):

We're sure that p(1) and p(2) are some values found as results of
the limits, so limits exist. Hence we need to eliminate denominators
by simplifying.

$$ \lim_{{x \to 1}} \frac{p(x)}{x - 1} = p(1) $$

When we write $1$ in place of x, the denominator is $0$. Since we know that the limit exists, there must be $\frac{0}{0}$ undefinition. So, we can say $p(1) = 0$

$$ \lim_{{x \to 2}} \frac{p(x)}{x - 2} = p(2) $$

In the same way, when we write $2$ in place of x, the denominator is $0$. Since we know that the limit exists, there must be $\frac{0}{0}$ undefinition. So, we can say $p(2) = 0$

Further, the 4th degree polynomial must include both $(x-1)$ and $(x-2)$ as multipliers because when we write 1 or 2, we can obtain $0$.

$$P(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(ax^{2}+bx+c)$$

When we write the polynomial in the limits, we obtain the following results.

$$\lim_{{x \to 1}} \frac{p(x)}{x - 1} = \lim_{{x \to 1}} \frac{(x-1)(x-2)(ax^{2}+bx+c)}{x - 1} = \lim_{{x \to 1}} {(x-2)(ax^{2}+bx+c)} = 0$$

$$\lim_{{x \to 2}} \frac{p(x)}{x - 2} = \lim_{{x \to 2}} \frac{(x-1)(x-2)(ax^{2}+bx+c)}{x - 2} = \lim_{{x \to 2}} {(x-1)(ax^{2}+bx+c)} = 0$$

For $(ax^{2}+bx+c)$, which is $q(x)$, we can say it must be $(x-1)*(x-2)$ as well. That's because to get $0$ in $\lim_{{x \to 1}} {(x-2)(ax^{2}+bx+c)} = 0$ while $x$ approaches to $0$, $x-2$ cannot be $0$. So, there must exist a $(x-1)$ in it. The same way is true for the other limit which approaches to $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information to the provided solution of the problem. Let's start with a look at the two given limits:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\lim_{{x \to 1}} \frac{p(x)}{x - 1}}&\color{blue}{= p(1)} \tag{1}\\
\color{blue}{\lim_{{x \to 2}} \frac{p(x)}{x - 2}}&\color{blue}{= p(2)}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

At first we recall that a polynomial
\begin{align*}
&p:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\\
&x\to p(x)
\end{align*}
is a function defined for *any* value $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Since the right-hand side of (1) is $p(1)$ which is a value in $\mathbb{R}$ we conclude the limit
\begin{align*}
\lim_{{x \to 1}} \frac{p(x)}{x - 1}
\end{align*}
exists. We also see that the denominator $x-1$ is zero when $x=1$. But since the limit exists, this factor must be cancelled by a factor $(x-1)$ of the numerator $p(x)$.

We conclude $x-1|p(x)$ and $x=1$ is a zero of $p$. In the same way we get from (2) that $x-2|p(x)$ and $x=2$ is a zero of the polynomial $p$. We conclude
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{p(1)=0}\qquad\mathrm{and}\qquad \color{blue}{p(2)=0}.\tag{3}
\end{align*}

It follows from (3) that the fourth degree polynomial $p$ has a representation
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{p(x)=(x-1)(x-2)q(x)}\tag{4}
\end{align*}
with $q$ a polynomial of degree $2$.

> We can now *again* conveniently use the limits (1) and (2). We derive from (3) and (4)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{0}&=p(1)=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{p(x)}{x-1}
> =\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{(x-1)(x-2)q(x)}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to 1}(x-2)q(x)\\
> &\color{blue}{\,\,=-q(1)}\tag{5}\\
> \color{blue}{0}&=p(2)=\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{p(x)}{x-2}
> =\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{(x-1)(x-2)q(x)}{x-2}=\lim_{x\to 2}(x-1)q(x)\\
> &\color{blue}{\,\,=q(2)}\tag{6}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We see from (5) and (6) that both $1$ and $2$ are also zeros of the polynomial $q$. Since $q$ is a polynomial of degree $2$ it has a representation
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{q(x)=a(x-1)(x-2)}
> \end{align*}
> with $a$ the coefficient of $x^2$ in $q$.

Since the problem also states that the highest degree term of $p$ has coefficient equal to $1$ we see that $a=1$ and we can finally conclude
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{p(x)}&=(x-1)(x-2)q(x)\\
&\color{blue}{\,\,=(x-1)^2(x-2)^2}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Note that for $x\neq1$, we have $p(x)=\frac{p(x)}{x-1}\cdot(x-1)$.
Since the polynomial $p$ is continuous at $x=1$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
p(1) & = & \lim_{x\rightarrow1}p(x)\\
 & = & \lim_{x\rightarrow1}[\frac{p(x)}{x-1}\cdot(x-1)]\\
 & = & \lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{p(x)}{x-1}\cdot\lim_{x\rightarrow1}(x-1)\\
 & = & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
In the above, we have used the fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{p(x)}{x-1}$
exists and $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}(x-1)=0$. This shows that $x=1$
is a zero for the polynomial $p(x)$. By Factor Theorem, $p(x)=(x-1)^{k}q(x)$
for some polynomial $q(x)$ and $k\geq1$, with $q(1)\neq0$. It is
given that $\lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{p(x)}{x-1}=p(1)$. Therefore,
\begin{eqnarray*}
p'(1) & = & \lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{p(x)-p(1)}{x-1}\\
 & = & \lim_{x\rightarrow1}\frac{p(x)}{x-1}\\
 & = & p(1).\\
 & = & 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
We go to show that $k\geq2$. Prove by contradiction. Suppose the
contrary that $k=1$, then $p'(x)=q(x)+(x-1)q'(x)$. In particular,
$0=p'(1)=q(1)$, which is a contradiction.

Repeat the above argument, we can show that $q(x)$ contains a factor
$(x-2)^{l}$ for some $l\geq2$. Hence, we may write $q(x)=(x-2)^{l}h(x)$
for some polynomial $h(x)$. Now, $p(x)=(x-1)^{k}(x-2)^{l}h(x)$ with
$k\geq2$, $l\geq2$. Since $p(x)$ is a degree 4 polynomial, it follows
that $k=l=2$ and $h(x)$ is a constant polynomial. It is given that
the coefficient of $x^{4}$ in $p(x)$ is $1$, so $h(x)=1$. That
is, $p(x)=(x-1)^{2}(x-2)^{2}$.